# Calculate New Value From Previous populated value from .map()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, array.prototype.map

I am Making a Table in react Js using the .map()function. In the last `<td>` of the table, I am calculating the taxed amount of the product from a function. This amount fills in every row `<td>` specified for them.

```
 {
          (!cr.items.length < 1) &&
           cr.items.map((item , ind) => {
               return(
                      <td scope="col">{(item) ? taxedValue(item.quantity , item.salesInfo.unitPrice , item.discount , item.tax) :null}</td>
                 </tr>
                 )
        })
 }
```

Function `taxedValue` return  a new amount. There can be many rows for this. What I want is to Get the sum of all the previously taxedValue rows.

Like When Map returns these row

```
<tr><td>1<td></td>
<tr><td>2<td></td>
```

I want to add {1+2} = 3(//get this as my total amount to access it anywhere in the code//}
I tried calling a state function with an initial value 0. But gets an error `Too much re-render`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be easy to simply add totaling a sum in the `array.prototype.map` function, but this callback is to be a pure function without side-effects.

I would suggest just computing the total separately using `array.prototype.reduce`. If computing the taxed value twice per render cycle is prohibitive then refactor the code to compute the taxed value once and inject it into the data you want to map *and* add it to a total sum.

```
const computeTotalTaxedValue = cr.items.reduce(
  (total, item) => item ? taxedValue(item.quantity, item.salesInfo.unitPrice, item.discount, item.tax) : 0,
  0,
);
```

If computing the taxed value twice for each item twice per render cycle is prohibitive then compute it once and inject it into the data and compute a sum.

```
const [totalTaxedValue, setTotalTaxedValue] = useState(0);
const [taxedValues, setTaxedValues] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  let totalTaxedValue = 0;
  const taxedValues = [];

  cr.items.forEach(item => {
    const taxValue = item ? taxedValue(item.quantity, item.salesInfo.unitPrice, item.discount, item.tax) : null;
    totalTaxedValue += taxValue;
    taxedValues.push(taxValue);
  });

  setTotalTaxedValue(totalTaxedValue);
  setTaxedValues(taxedValues);
}, [cr.items]);

...

{
  (!taxedValues.length < 1) &&
  taxedValues.map((taxValue, ind) => <td scope="col">{taxValue}</td>
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do that in a separate function to keep that logic isolated. What you can do is define a variable and increment the value in every iteration of the `map` and then, in the last element, render an additional column. Something like this:

```
const renderColumns = () => {
  let total = 0;

  if (!cr.items.length < 1) {
    return cr.items.map((item , ind) => {
      const value = item ? taxedValue(item.quantity , item.salesInfo.unitPrice , item.discount , item.tax) : null;
      total += value || 0;

      return (
        <>
          <td scope="col">{value}</td>
          {ind === cr.items.length - 1 ? (
            <td>{total}</td>
          ) : null}
        </>
      );
    });
  }

  return null;
};
```